# RoR need correct coding for employee - user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user table and an employee table.  They have a one-to-one relationship.
When I create a time-entry record, I would like to automatically assign the current employee.
What I have access to is the current_user.
The employee table has a foreign key (user_id).

I tried this in the form - but it didn't work:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :employee_id, :value => current_user.employee.employee_id %>
```

Do I need to add a foreign key to the user table = employee_id ?

Thanks

Comment: No you don't need a employee_id in the users table. What error are you getting? Did you set the relation between time records and employees properly?

Comment: This isn't related to this question, exactly, but what reason do you have for using an employee table?  Since it's just a one-to-one relationship I don't really see the benefit of adding the extra queries just to get `current_user.employee`.  Is there something that prevents you from having the employee attributes on the user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your employee model

```
belongs_to :user
```

and your user model

```
has_one :employee
```

Is that right?

If so, it might be as simple as changing the hidden field value to

```
current_user.employee.id
```

(rather than current_user.employee.employee_id).

If that doesn't work, can you post exactly how you're constructing the one-to-one relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to set the `employee_id` in the controller. If `@entry` is an instance of the model (call it `Entry`) that you're building the form for, consider doing something like this:

```
# in controller +new+ method:
@entry.employee_id = current_user.employee.id
```

The value of the hidden field should then be populated automagically:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :employee_id %>
```

Of course, you may not even need to set this in the form at all. Assuming the form is being posted to a `create` method somewhere, why not just set the variable there?

```
# in controller +create+ method:
@entry = Entry.new(params[:entry])
@entry.employee_id = current_user.employee.id

if @entry.save
  # do stuff
end
```

As you will probably need to at least check the id anyway to make sure no funny business is taking place, this might be the way to go.